# How to position text over an image without fixed height in css

Tags: html, css

I used example from tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

I don't understand why my text aligned to bottom right corner of outer `div` instead of image, can some one explain why? and how to resolve this issue without having fixed height container.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axhqn2b5/2/

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50"> 
   <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right aligned to outer container, why?</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">line<br/>line<br/>line<br/>line<br/>line</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right aligned to inner box</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: lightgreen;
}
img {
    width: 100%; 
    border: red 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

It shows that image height is less then outer container height. I can use text "bottom" attribute to align it, but may be there is better solution.

Comment: `position: absolute` means it's placed relative to the nearest positioned _ancestor_. So it will never be positioned relative to a sibling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the image diplay property.

Add:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

The image by default is rendered as an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

the difference you see i because of the whitespace below the image.

to fix that just add vertical-align:top; to the image

```
img {
    width: 100%; 
    border: red 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align:top; /*add*/
}
```

and now your text will be at the same position.

both examples you gave are actually positioned at bottom right of .container